# Make all elements of a string[] array into a single string with linq

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

say I have an array with some strings in it

```
string[] array = {"item1", "item2"};
```

and now I want to use linq to on a single line take all the strings and put them into an array with a space between them
I have tried

```
args.Select(x => x.ToString() + " ").ToString()
```

but this returns

[image: Output Image]

It is important to me that the code is on a single line of code, as it is not very clean in my standards or fitting to loop through with a foreach and add it to a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `String.Join(" ", array);` it should do the trick